# Many-to-Many, Unidirectional, Self-referencing association in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to 'link' some objects. Imagine you have Person table with these records:

- Barack Obama
- Obama Barack
- Barack Hussein Obama

As you can see it is one the same person. I would like to have association that stores alternative persons. For example for Person with `ID`=1 and `NAME`=Barack Obama `linkedPersons` would look like this:

```
linkedPersons:
    Obama Barack
    Barack Hussein Obama
    (optionally with Barack Obama itself)
```

IMHO it should be Many-to-Many, Unidirectional, Self-referencing association but I have no idea how to implement such an association.

Comment: There is bidirectional example in [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing). It can be your starting point.

Comment: @MolecularMan this example uses 2 fields in Entity but I want to have only one. While I add some linked persons in for one user they are also available for another one in the same field.

Comment: I think if you remove `$friendsWithMe` and `inversedBy` it should work as you'd want.

Comment: It won't because in join table you have two different columns and record id1=1,id2=2 is not the same as id1=2,id2=1. In this solution I would have to add linked users in each of 3 mentioned persons and I want to do it for 1 only (no matter which one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do simple ManyToMany unidirectional mapping. On relation just relate both users. This would make additional records in database (A -> B and B -> A), but I think it should work as you want.

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinTable(name="alternateUsers",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="alternate_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $alternateUsers;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->alternateUsers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addAlternateUser(User $user) {
        $this->alternateUsers[] = $user;
        $user->alternateUsers[] = $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid $user (alternate one) is never persisted. Probably because it is not modified by the form.

Comment: Well, you can persist it in your controller. You have to persist your newly created entities in either way, don't you?
OR you can configure to cascade persist operation via this relation. @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"}). See more at http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html?highlight=cascade#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations